# Show that $a_{n }= \frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n + 2} + ... + \frac{1}{2n}$ for n ≥ 1 is a bounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

How do I show that $a_{n}= \frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n + 2} + ... + \frac{1}{2n}$ for n ≥ 1, is bounded by using $a_{n} ≤ \frac{n}{n+1}$ where n ≥ 1.

I know to show that a sequence is bounded you show it is bounded both above and below but I am unsure as to how to use $a_{n} ≤ \frac{n}{n+1}$ where n ≥ 1

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: $a_n\le n/(n+1)=1-1/(n+1)\lt 1$.Now the lower bound?

Comment: For lower bound use that $n+k\leq n+n$, $1\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: $$
\frac{1}{2} = n \times \frac{1}{{2n}} < a_n  < n \times \frac{1}{{n + 1}} = 1 - \frac{1}{{n + 1}} < 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

$0\lt a_n \le \dfrac{n}{n+1} \lt 1$

Answer (score 0):

If you know harmonic numbers and their properties
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{n+k}=H_{2n}-H_n$$
Now, using the asymptotics
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12  p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$
apply it twice to get
$$a_n=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{16 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$ In fact, it is an alternating series and then 
$$\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n} < a_n <\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{16 n^2}$$